# Ant with Hudson War

Tags: java, ant, hudson

I have built my application in Hudson. It is working fine, but I need a link on the Hudson page where I can download the war file generated by Hudson, so that I can download and deploy it on the server. Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Hudson configuration for your project, look at the Post-build actions. "Archive artifacts" does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In general, Hudson publishes your project's artifacts (the JARs and WARs it builds) in the "*Last Successful Artifacts*" section of your project's page.

You should be able to find that section at `http://$SERVER/hudson/job/$PROJECT_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/`
if you have configured your project to archive artifacts.